# wrong output of assembly program

Tags: assembly, x86-16

This code should display date in form of year:month:day but year shows as 20f4 and day shows as 58 and I can't figure out why.

```
; return: CX = year (1980-2099). DH = month. DL = day. AL = day of week (00h=Sunday)  
displaydate:
mov ah,2Ah
int 21h   ; get date

mov dl,' '
mov ah,02h
int 21h
mov dl,' '
mov ah,02h
int 21h  
mov dl,'2'
mov ah,02h
int 21h 
mov dl,'0'
mov ah,02h
int 21h 


mov al,cl ; year
mov  ah,0 
mov bl,10
div bl 

 mov years1,al ; number
mov years2,ah ;remainder  
add years1,30h
add years2,30h;asci code 

mov dl,years1
mov ah,02h
int 21h   
 mov dl,years2
mov ah,02h
int 21h 
mov dl,':'
mov ah,02h
int 21h
;--------------------------------------------- 

mov al,dh ;months
mov  ah,0  
mov bl,10
div bl  

mov month1,al ; number
mov month2,ah ;remainder  
add month1,30h
add month2,30h;asci code 

mov dl,month1
mov ah,02h
int 21h   
 mov dl,month2
mov ah,02h
int 21h 
mov dl,':'

mov ah,02h
int 21h  
;-------------------------------------------------
 mov al,DL  ;days
mov  ah,0  
mov bl,10
div bl  

mov days1,al ; number
mov days2,ah ;remainder  
add days1,30h
add days2,30h;asci code 

mov dl,days1
mov ah,02h
int 21h   
 mov dl,days2
mov ah,02h
int 21h
```

Comment: You have not listed any troubleshooting or debugging steps that you have already followed.  The very first one should be, "Step through it with a debugger and see at which point you begin to have behavior that you do not understand."  More often than not, this will allow *you* to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov al,cl ; year
> mov  ah,0 
> mov bl,10
> div bl
> ```

Why do you only use the `CL` register here?
If you got the date from DOS via function 2Ah then you have recieved a number for the year in the whole of the `CX` register. This will be in the range 1980-2099. Your program needs to subtract 2000 from this value before processing *the years within the century (0-99)*:

```
mov ax, cx  ;Year
sub ax, 2000
mov bl, 10
div bl
```

---

> day shows as 58 and i can't fiure why

The number for the day is kept in the `DL` register, but the time that your program is ready to process it, the number in `DL` has been changed by all the intervening code to display characters through DOS! Meaning *you* put many other values in it. Use `push`/`pop` to not loose the day value:

```
mov ah,2Ah
int 21h   ; get date
PUSH DX   <<< This preserves the day value in DL

;do all the other stuff

POP DX    <<< This restores the day value in DL
;-------------------------------------------------
mov al,DL  ;days
mov  ah,0  
mov bl,10
div bl  
mov days1,al ; number
mov days2,ah ;remainder  
add days1,30h
add days2,30h;asci code
```